# Interact with other desktop-applications in windows using C# winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, desktop-application, interaction

I was wondering if its possible to interact with other programs someone with my program. For example clicking a button on another program etc. etc. I'm not sure if this is even possible but if it is could someone provide a little sample code in C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [UI Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to interact with other applications.

Answer (score 4):

You could just create and send messages to the other process. You will have to use P/Invoke for this from C# code.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/345d85e8-cc5f-4508-b3f2-74ee43521169/) is some code that should point you into the right direction.