# Running an installer from within C#

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I need to write code to download and run a program, e.g. notepad++ (npp.5.9.3.Installer.exe) this can be found on the web. 
I run it with the ProcessStartInfo class. However when I normally execute the notepad++ installer, it will show me a few steps before actually installing, like choose language, path etc.

Is there any way to programatically skip these steps, and install the software? I hope my question is clear. If it helps, I also attach the method that so far only starts the installer

```
        private int RunFile()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(GetFileFullPath());
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
                if (process.HasExited)
                    return process.ExitCode;
            }
        }
```

Shall I pass some arguments for this to work? 
Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some installers which supports -s or -silent switches which means that when you install a software by passing -s switch to installer and it will silently install with default options. Try to find out whether your installer supports that or not

Comment: For people looking also for an answer: this post has been noted as the answer, whereas _CD.._ post gives the actual answer. Check _CD.._ answer.

Comment: i marked this post as the answer, since it was providing the info that I needed. CD gives specific for notepad++, but in my thread starting i mentioned that notepad is just an example (note the e.g. in my question); in short, I was looking for a more general answer. Also you provided both the general and specific answer, but Haris Hasan was faster :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `npp.5.9.3.Installer.exe /S` for unattended installation of notepad++, and `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\uninstall.exe /S` for uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

you have to drive the installation emulating the user. It is possible send kind of command(message) to the other window from a C# application

have a look at the below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/345d85e8-cc5f-4508-b3f2-74ee43521169/

[Interact with other desktop-applications in windows using C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912879/interact-with-other-desktop-applications-in-windows-using-c-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

A wellwritten installer have options for silent installs with no user interface. If the installer is an .msi file there are [options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_SetUI) that can be passed to `msiexec` to make a silent install.

For other install systems there are sometimes options to. Automating installations without user involvement is a common task for system administrators, so if you have questions on a specific installation package I would suggerst asking at [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com) or [AppDeploy](http://www.appdeploy.com). Unfortunately there are many bad installation programs out there that doesn't support silent install.

Answer (score 1):

This will ONLY depend on the installer (*npp.5.9.3.Installer.exe*). You have to search if the installer provides options that can be used in command line, such as `silentinstall`.

EDIT: You can use the /S (capital `S`) option for Notepad++ to perform a silent install.