# How to make a custom installer

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have already asked this question before, and it was closed "TOO BROAD". But I am asking again but just need a little introduction to solve my problem. I want to make a installer that will install other software such as Skype, Google Chrome etc. 
On my previous post I got the following comment:

> Here a start: write any C# program and than write a script (probably
>   .cmd for Windows) to copy all necessary binaries/resource to other
>   machine... Make it work on more than one destination machine... on
>   machine without correct version of .Net... without admin rights...
>   just for one user ... and for all users... add readable logging ...
>   and call home... Should be enough for first year.

I do not understand this comment, please someone tell me in more simpler language. I want to make this on Windows Forms using C#. 
Where should I start??? 
How do I access the installer files and execute them using C#??
Please do not close this post as I want to make this thing and I need help.

Comment: Why don't you just launch each installer from C#, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6856143

Comment: Let me look at this thread and try it then I will post here again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I would say this is indeed *much* too broad for StackOverflow. I'm not even going to ask where those constraints came from or why you need to follow them. But do note that such a thing will almost certainly violate the redistribution terms of the EULA (license agreements) for many/most/all these programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Run an exe from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code)

This will execute the .exe of your chrome, skype (...) installers. But then you will have to go through the complete installation dialog of set programm and im not quite sure, if that feeds your purpose...

What that comment describes: install all programms on your machine, then locate the installed files and build a script, that copies these files on the target machine. Then he tells you how to test your application

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Setup and Deployment project template for this. In Visual Studio, this is listed  under "Other Project Types" node of the new project dialog. Please refer to the link to get more info on it. http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html

If you have to perform custom actions during installation, you can make use of Installer Classes also.

You can run code on several events like before installation, after installation etc. You can do a lot of basic things like adding your registry entries, add dependency files, showing up in Start menu etc. This one is just a basic install creator. If you need more advanced one, there are lot of paid and free utilities available there.